# Two Threads calling one Method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method which writes a XML- File like this:

```
private void doProcess() {

    Element rootElement = mDoc.createElement("Test");
    mDoc.appendChild(rootElement);

....... I build the whole document here... 
}
```

But this method can be called by multiple Threads, so for example if thwo threads call this method on the same time i get an

```
): org.w3c.dom.DOMException: Only one root element allowed
```

I already tried it with an reentrantlock, but this didn´t work...Can somebody give me a hint?

Edit:

I dont build the Document with multiple Threads...Every Call of my Method builds his own Doc...So sometimes in my Application it could happen that my Method will be called two times at the same time...And there´s my Problem...

Comment: A `Document` can only have one root element. You need to append children to that element directly. You cannot simply add multiple elements to a `Document` as that would result in multiple root elements. Note that a `Document` is not threadsafe as so all operations on that `Document` much be `synchronized`.

Comment: The error is about the document has more than one `root` element, it's not a thread thing.

Comment: Create the root node in the parent thread and add the elements in the child thread.

Comment: As long as you only access variables which are method scoped, I cannot see any issues arising here. Issues with multithreading start once you access member variables / class variables. So either move your variable `mDoc` to method scope, or avoid the threading issues by e.g using a `ThreadLocal` variable, but this really depends on your problem at hand.

Comment: Why are you using multiple threads to create a single Document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question you state:

> I dont build the Document with multiple Threads...Every Call of my Method builds his own Doc

Currently the code given shares a single doc between all calls to the function. In order to have each call to the function work on it's own document, you need to modify the code such that each call has it's own doc.

This can be done either by creating and returning a new document object

```
private XMLDocument doProcess() {
  XMLDocument mDoc = new XMLDocument(); // or simmilar depending on XML library
  Element rootElement = mDoc.createElement("Test");
  mDoc.appendChild(rootElement);

  // ....... I build the whole document here... 

  return mDoc; //return the document object
}
```

Or, by passing the document object in as a parameter

```
private void doProcess(XMLDocument mDoc) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

An xml can has only ONE root, so this may be answer to your question. You can instantiate an root element outside this method and add element to this root inside method each time.